# Not able to clone entity in Jpa

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have two entities. one Entity Conditions has OneToMany Mapping with Sites and the other entity sites has manyToOneMapping with Conditions. Now I want to copy conditions with all its attributes update few values and persist it as a new entity.

```
 public class Condition{
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "condition",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
        private List<Sites> sites;
    }

    public class Sites{
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=Condition.class,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "conditionId")
        private condition condition;
    }
```

And in the service layer i have done this :-

```
entityManager.detach(condition);
condition.setId(0L);

conditionRepository.save(condition);
```

I am getting the below error:-

```
{
    "timestamp": 1509530470031,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "java.lang.RuntimeException",
    "message": "javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: co.src..entity.condition",
    "path": "/project/reviseProjectDetails"
}
```

Any One who has idea about this issue please help!!

Answer (score 0):

`@OneToMany` means that one `Sites`can't belong to two `Condition`.

When you do

```
entityManager.detach(condition);
```

you continue to have `sites` persistent. You can try to use `cascade = CascadeType.DETACH`.